.NET MAUI - Is it possible to detect (and don't block) native touch and TapGestureRecognizer?[Android]
I have a simplified code:
<MyCustomView>
<MyChildView/>
</MyCustomView>

Inside MyChildView:
<Content>
  <MyClicableView>
    <MyClicableView.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command=.../>
    <MyClicableView.GestureRecognizers/>
  
    <Label Text=.../>
  </MyClicableView>
</Content>

For MyCustomView I have a Handler which on connect subscribes to the touch event:
protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiScrollView platformView)
{
    base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    platformView.Touch += OnTouchPressed;
}

When I click outside of MyClicableView native touch event for MyCustomView is detected. When I click on MyClicableView the TapGesture command is execute. Only thing that I want do (if is possible) when I do some move on MyClicableView the native touch from MyCustomView is disabled and it doesn't detect the touch. Do you know if there is a way that both the touches can be detected?

You need to set Handled property to false in your OnTouchPressed's touched event args. This ensures event is not consumed by your handler alone.
private void OnTouchPressed(object sender, Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = false;

   //do other stuff
}

